# Http.get() on images - How do I determine if the image is valid?

Tags: node.js, http-get

I'm using Node.js to download images from a server and save them. Occasionally I get served corrupted images that in-turn break some video rendering in another part of my program. I'd like to validate these images before they're saved.

Right now I have a function that looks like this:

```
function saveImage(res, destination, imageName, url) {
  var imgName = './' + destination + '/' + imageName + '.jpg';
  var type = res.headers['content-type'];
  if (type === 'image/jpg' || type === 'image/jpeg') {
      res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imgName));
  } else {
      console.log('corrupt Image caught: ', url,' headers: ',type);
  }
}
```

You'll see that I'm already checking the content type. This actually doesn't stop some of the bad images. They appear to have the correct headers, but are saved as 0 KB files.

Is there an easy way to check the file size of the image that isn't reliant on the content-length? Fron my understanding that isn't always set.

Comment: I'd also read the image into an appropriate image loader to verify the format is correct as well (and detect mislabelled files).

Comment: @Dai could you please expand upon that.